# Make n number of arrays using the value from the same object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am currently trying to separate the orderItems and display them as individual.
Right now if the user wants to add new item, and the item already exists, it just increments the quantity and does not duplicate them.

As a result I got this

```json
[
  {
    "id": "cla7dnfln000mvprgde8b9ovh",
    "name": null,
    "price": 134,
    "quantity": 3,
    "orderId": "cla7dmh5v000ivprghh27g22z",
    "menuItemId": "cl9t45hry002uvpr9sp9jxl1t",
    "comments": null,
    "stock": null,
    "menuItem": {
      "id": "cl9t45hry002uvpr9sp9jxl1t",
      "image": "https://madre-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/logo-madre-cafe-header.svg",
      "name": "Especiales Item #2",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
      "price": "134",
      "available": true,
      "menuCategoryId": "cl9t45hqu000tvpr9fjw67ype"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "cla8ehie20000vpusxqvp0kcq",
    "name": null,
    "price": 223,
    "quantity": 1,
    "orderId": "cla7dmh5v000ivprghh27g22z",
    "menuItemId": "cl9t45hry0010vpr9q3pjo2kc",
    "comments": null,
    "stock": null,
    "menuItem": {
      "id": "cl9t45hry0010vpr9q3pjo2kc",
      "image": "https://madre-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/logo-madre-cafe-header.svg",
      "name": "Hot Cakes Item #2",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
      "price": "223",
      "available": true,
      "menuCategoryId": "cl9t45hqu000nvpr9pwqkk3gj"
    }
  }
]
```

What I want to do is make a new object with for 3 "especiales Item #2" but separated.
Something like:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Especiales Item #2",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "price": "134"
  },
  {
    "name": "Especiales Item #2",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "price": "134"
  },
  {
    "name": "Especiales Item #2",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "price": "134"
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you want to get only menu items from the array with name, description, and price key?

Comment: yes, I want to separate the order items or menu items as an individual depending of the quantity. Im thinking something like get the quantity with order.map and then using Array.from(quantity) but its not going well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to flatten all menu items separately, you may loop through the array as follows.

```js
const orderList = [
  {
    "id": "cla7dnfln000mvprgde8b9ovh",
    "name": null,
    "price": 134,
    "quantity": 3,
    "orderId": "cla7dmh5v000ivprghh27g22z",
    "menuItemId": "cl9t45hry002uvpr9sp9jxl1t",
    "comments": null,
    "stock": null,
    "menuItem": {
      "id": "cl9t45hry002uvpr9sp9jxl1t",
      "image": "https://madre-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/logo-madre-cafe-header.svg",
      "name": "Especiales Item #2",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
      "price": "134",
      "available": true,
      "menuCategoryId": "cl9t45hqu000tvpr9fjw67ype"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "cla8ehie20000vpusxqvp0kcq",
    "name": null,
    "price": 223,
    "quantity": 1,
    "orderId": "cla7dmh5v000ivprghh27g22z",
    "menuItemId": "cl9t45hry0010vpr9q3pjo2kc",
    "comments": null,
    "stock": null,
    "menuItem": {
      "id": "cl9t45hry0010vpr9q3pjo2kc",
      "image": "https://madre-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/logo-madre-cafe-header.svg",
      "name": "Hot Cakes Item #2",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
      "price": "223",
      "available": true,
      "menuCategoryId": "cl9t45hqu000nvpr9pwqkk3gj"
    }
  }
]

const getMenuItems = (arr) => {
  const items = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].quantity; j++) {
      items.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return items;
};

const menuItems = getMenuItems(orderList);
```